# Client socket read "freezes"

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, groovy, stream

I want to write a simple web proxy, for exercise. Here's the code I have so far:

```
def g = new Proxy()
g.serverPort = 9000
println "starting"
g.eachClient { Socket client ->
    println "got a client"
    try {
        client.withStreams { input,output ->
            String text = input.text
            println "received $text from client"
            client.close()
        }
    } catch(IOException io) {
        println "IO error. Probably client disconnected"
        //io.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

the thing is, the line :

```
String text = input.text
```

consumes all the available data in the Socket's InputStream. If the client isn't closing the connection, that method will just wait until it can read a end of file character ( if I remember correctly ). What do I have to prevent this from happening, and have the client's string available ASAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to check the documentation on [ObjectInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).  Do `length = input.available` to get the number of available bytes at the present time, then use `input.read(buffer, offset, length)` to read in exactly as many bytes are available.  You'll probably want to launch a new thread for every new connection which transparently manages this buffer in the background, unless you're making a single-threaded proxy to begin with.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! One more question please, how does java know how many bytes are available?

Comment: That's more a question of the underlying operating system's socket library, which Java abstracts away for you.  You can see an example of how to do this using C in a *nix operating system here: http://www.dholm.com/2008/05/13/available-socket-bytes/